# Altering attr string based on current attr value

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have a combo box listener for expansion. Upon expansion, it performs some styling on each element with a particular class within the combo box options. One of the desired changes is an alteration to an attribute based on the current attribute's value. Using `this` returns undefined.

```
expand   : function(combo) {
  $('.status-0').addClass('greyed-out');
  $('.status-0').attr('attrname', $(this).attr('attrname') + ' is status 0');
}
```

I'd like for each element with `.status-0` to have their attribute string have "is status 0" appended to it. The attribute is an ExtJS tooltip, but the solution should be applicable to any attribute type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `function` overload of `$.attr`, which accepts a `function` which will receive two parameters, index and the attribute value. `this` will refer the the element. But we don't need it here since we can just use attribute's value which is passed.

```
$('.status-0').attr('attrname', function(_, attrVal){
     return attrVal + ' is status 0';
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks for explaining it, too! (Will accept as soon as time limits up)

Comment: @Chris only glad to help :)